# Go packages not running as sudo

Tags: apt, bash, sudo, paths, golang

I installed golang via `sudo apt install golang-go`

I installed some go packages, like `go get -u github.com/tomnomnom/assetfinder`

I can run my packages without sudo, but when I do use sudo, the following error shows up:

`sudo: assetfinder: command not found`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to updatethe `secure_path` option in your `/etc/sudoers` file to include some of the paths from your `~/.profile` file.

To do this, run `sudo visudo` and edit the secure path line:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:{path to command(s)}"
```

***Note:** Be sure to change `{path to command(s)}` to the actual path that people using `sudo` will need.*

Save the file and, the next time you run a `sudo` command, the directory you need will be in `sudo`'s $PATH.

Hope this gives you what you need.